# I can't debug on an Android device on Ubuntu running on WMware

Tags: android, ubuntu, vmware

I'm asking the question here and not in AskUbuntu because I hope I'll find some Android developers that have already had this problem.

I use "Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS-Linux 2.6.32-45-generic x86_64" running on WMWare Player 5.0.1 running on Windows7 64bit.

The problem I have is that when I plug my Android device I get the error "The connection for the USB device was unsuccessful. Driver error".

The driver on Windows is installed and it works. I can debug on Windows.

The `lsusb`command does not list the attached device.

I googled it and I found that maybe the problem is that VMWare player does not support USB3 yet. I did not find a way around this problem. I tried to uninstall the USB3 driver but the result was that the USB port stopped working. Did someone manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could see so far the only available solutions are:

1) Go back to an older machine with no USB3

2) Use a newer machine with Windows8 (it supports the drivers supported by VMWare)

3) Install the new Intel drivers if they are compatible with your machine.

see also [VMWare forum](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2138646)

Comment: I copied the same VM on an older machine with no USB3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times this can be caused by not having drivers for your device, as well as the usb drivers from your sdk manager. Im using windows it sounds like a similiar problem I had. Also if you can run a command prompt from the folder cotaining your adb.exe file try typing "adb devices" to see if you see your device

Comment: adb devices does not return the attached device. Even lsusb doesn't.

Comment: did you download the drivers specific to your device and the drivers from sdk manager

Comment: with vmware it should be enough to install the drivers on the hosting machine. And yes I did install the drivers on the hosting machine.